# WSO2-OAuth2.0-ExternalAccessToken

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a unique scenario in which we need to sync external oauth access-token with wso2am-key-manager.

Scenario is as follows, user login to our internal IDP server and IDP server generates access-token upon successful verification of user credentials so now the requirement is the UI(application) should be able to invoke API on wso2am using that access-token which was generated by IDP. So that is only possible if we sync that external-access-token to Wso2am-Key-manager. I am not able fit this requirement with available grant types, password, client-credential as all these grant types generates new access-token which we dont want.

please advise how to achieve it. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 API Manager supports to configure external key manager[1].So you can configure your IDP as keymanager to WSO2 APIM

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Configuring+a+Third-Party+Key+Manager

Comment: Thanks @Jenananthan I have seen this article before. It has given example with Surf OAuth. So this way we are making our IDP as Key-Manager for WSO2 and all Keys will be generated with IDP once i do that. But for this I should write KeyManagerClientImpl class, what should be content of of this class ?  This does not help in syncing access-token.. I want to sync IDP generated access-token to WSO2 am-key-manager. thanks for help.